# Custom login redirect to default login page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new from Magento i want to custom login in cms page. so that i used default login in that cms page. But if i enter wrong password it redirect to default login page how to fix this thing.

My code

```
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
            <div class="market_place_login_ctrl">
                <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form" class="market_place_login_ctrl">
                            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
                             <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="text" name="login[username]" placeholder="Your Email ID (username)" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="Password" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-md-2">
                                <div class="row">
                                <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span ><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                                </div>


                           </div>
                           <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>">Forgot password?</a>

                             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                </form>     
            </div>   





    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: but error message redirect to default login page

Answer (score 0):

You should use an URL rewrite for that, because the login URL is hard coded in Magento (see app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php -> `const ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN = 'customer/account/login';`)

But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772720/is-there-a-way-to-change-login-page-url-in-magento points out how to handle that.

Brief explanition:

The controller for the customer login checks for valid login credentials, sets an error if needed and, in your case, sets the login url for redirection

(`$session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getLoginUrl());`).

The helper sets the hardcoded login URL and at the end the session gets redirected.

Comment: where i add this code\

Comment: This is just an explanation of Magento's behaviour. Check the linked SO answer to set things like you want.